# Azure Front Door(Standard) forwards IPV6 instead of IPv4 in the X-Forwarded-For header

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

We have a functionality where the admin can restrict users from accessing the apps who don't belong to a specific IP/IP range. Our applications were deployed behind a Application Gateway and it used to work fine with the X-Forwarded-For header giving the IPV4 address

We recently implemented Azure Front Door and the X-Forwarded-For header gives the IPV6 instead of the IPV4.

We are using Azure Front Door Standard, is there a way to make AFD forward IPV4 instead?
We couldn't find any settings/configs related to this on the Azure portal.